# How to check if 2 tables contain the the same columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, db2

I have to write a scheduled ETL job where I have to load the difference of the data between the source tables and the target tables. However it is possible that the difference is not just in the number of records, but in the data structure itself. Columns can be added/deleted/renamed.

If the difference would be in the number of records only, it would be easy-peasy a simple EXCEPT would do the job.
Now in my head the order would be:

1. Check if the column names are the same in the 2 tables (Main question: How to do this?)
2. If so, load the differences
3. If not then it implies another question: What is the best practice? Drop the table and recreate it based on the new source table, or start some altering on the target table?

Every suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please tag the database you're using

Comment: Fair point sorry, it is DB2

Comment: When asking for help with Db2, it is essential to specify (with tags or text) the __platform__ of the Db2-server ( Z/OS  , i-series,   linux/unix/windows) because the __system catalog views__ can be in different schemas per platform, and it is these views and tables that contain the data dictionary, which you can query to determine column names and data types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB2 supports the standard `information_schema.columns` table -- as well as bespoke naming conventions.  You can look at two tables using:

```
select c.column_name,
       (case when min(table_name) = max(table_name)
             then min(table_name) || ' only'
             else 'both'
        end)
from information_schema.columns c
where table_name in ('source', 'target') and
      table_schema = ?
group by column_name;
```

As for what to do when the data structure changes.  I think humans need to be involved in that process to figure out the best approach.  Typical options are:

- Ignore new columns.
- Set old columns that are missing to `NULL`.

However, there may be other approaches depending on the problem.

Comment: Add `GROUP BY c.column_name` at the end.